# Angular library component causes Reference Error in the application that uses it

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular11

I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'SomeLibraryComponent' before initialization

I have a library module / workspace I created and imported to my application project / workspace using package.json dependency and imported in my application main module definition.

After investigating the stacktrace I saw that it happens due to an attempt to initialize a ViewChild of another component 'SomeParentLibraryComponent':

```
@Component({
    selector:'some-parent',
    templateUrl: './some-parent.component.html'
})
export class SomeParentLibraryComponent {
    
    @ViewChild(SomeLibraryComponent, {static: false}) theCauseComponent: SomeLibraryComponent;
    .....
}

@Component({
    selector:'some-child',
    templateUrl: './some.component.html'
})
export class SomeLibraryComponent {
    .....
}
```

The template file './some-parent.component.ts':

```
<div>
    ...
    <some-child></some-child>
    ...
</div>
```

How to fix this? why does it happen?

I'm using Angular 11. Both application project (angular workspace 1) and library project (angular workspace 2) were generated using angular-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for the issue is to replace the type with a reference name from the HTML.
In the template file of the parent component (./some-parent.component.html), add a reference to the child:

```
<div>
    ...
    <some-child #theChild></some-child>
    ...
</div>
```

In the typescript file (*.ts) of the parent, change the reference from type to named:

```
@ViewChild('theChild', {static: false}) theCauseComponent: SomeLibraryComponent;
```

I don't know why this happens, but this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using static false so you can only access it in AfterViewInit. use static true if you want to use in before AfterViewInit or implement AfterViewInit in your component and use it in ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Read https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#example-2

Comment: I actually tried this solution but it didn't work. Changing to static true is probably correct though.